# Internet Resource which register all Ultra-long Gamma-Ray Bursts

Tags: black-hole, explosion

I read in a scientific magazine there was new gamma bursts that last longer than usual.

- One was detected during december 2010, also known as Christmas Burst: [GRB 101225A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRB_101225A)
- and another one in 9th of December 2011, [GRB 111209A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRB_111209A)

They were both detected by the "Swift" program and [this article goes into detail](http://www.dailygalaxy.com/my_weblog/2013/04/christmas-burst-of-2011-source-discovered-most-powerful-known-gamma-ray-blast-to-hit-earth-.html).

I do not know if there is another programs for GRB detection and I would be curious to find a resource on Internet which registers/records all Ultra-long Gamma-Ray Bursts on one single page/site (across all research/programs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess one of them you're referring to was [GRB 130427A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRB_130427A) (not in December of 2010 or 2011 tho, but in April 2013)? But yes, there are several such catalogs, as are different designators and phenomenological classification methods for these gamma-ray bursts (GBR). For example, *GRB 130427A* is a simple nomenclature that consists of a date of discovery (*130427* denotes 27th of April, 2013 and suffix A is just the first letter from the alphabet, increased when there's more than a single such event in a day), but it doesn't indicate e.g. its type or origin. The same GRB event is so cataloged under designator *CSS130502:113233+274156* in the [Catalina Real-time Transient Survey catalog](http://crts.caltech.edu/), *SDSS J113232.84+274155.4* in [Sloan Digital Sky Survey catalog](http://cas.sdss.org/dr7/en/), and so on.

So, as you can see, it would help if you could clarify which designators you saw, so we can identify the catalog easier. But not wanting to leave you empty-handed, one such catalog that is frequently used and is relatively easily searchable is the Goddard Space Flight Center's [GRBCAT (Gamma Ray Burst CATalog)](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/grbcat/) (on top of those already mentioned).

---

Post update to the question, I've managed to identify SWIFT pages for the two GRB events in question:

- [101225A](http://swift.gsfc.nasa.gov/archive/grb_table/fullview/101225A/)
- [111209A](http://swift.gsfc.nasa.gov/archive/grb_table/fullview/111209A/)

Catalog numbers, references and data are available on linked pages. And here is a [complete SWIFT GRB catalog](http://swift.gsfc.nasa.gov/archive/grb_table/fullview/) (note, it's rather long, listing all GRB in a single page).

Comment: Thank for your answer, I updated my question as a magazine was relating the Swift program.

Comment: Most SWIFT detected GRBs should be cataloged in GRBCAT too, but just to be sure, also check [on its own page](http://swift.gsfc.nasa.gov/archive/grb_table/) (It's searchable and can be filtered by years of detection ;).